# UITextView in UITableViewCell - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a costum UITableViewCell with an UITextView in it, but my TextView does not resize and if I scroll down the formatting of UITextView's content changes!

I have some objects in my costum cell's .h-file, but nothing else.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
AACTickerYellowCell * cell;

        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"yellowCell";
        cell = (AACTickerYellowCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[AACTickerYellowCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];

        cell.minuteLabel.text = [[dict objectAtIndex: [[dataManager getTickerObjects] count] - 1 - indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Minute"];

        cell.textView.delegate = self;
        cell.textView.text = [[dict objectAtIndex: [[dataManager getTickerObjects] count] - 1 - indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Text"];
        cell.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

        return cell;
```

'dict' is declared in my `-viewDidLoad:`.

Where are my two problems and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you resized your cell in the - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath UITableView Delegate?

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's not the problem!
The cell's height stays alsways the same, but its content is changing if its scrolls in!

Comment: This may be another stupid question...but I had this same problem and it ended being that I didn't have constraints put on my textview

Comment: I had this problem sometimes before, too, but I don't how I solved it.. :D